# Mobile hotspot was working with wifi-on; now it doesn't

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

Was sending internet service to my tablet through a newer Moto phone that was able to get internet from a Optimum hotspot. The tablet was unable to receive the signal.

Was using it this way for a few hours just before and it was working fine. Now when I turn on the mobile hotspot on the Moto the Wi-Fi automatically turns off. What gives??

Comment: Very few Android devices (with 2 sets of WiFi hardware) are capable of WiFi relay - you might have unknowingly left data on in the first case.

Comment: @AndyYan you might be right